# How to fill "department" for the author actually without department?

Tags: paper-submission

I found many journals require the department information for all authors during submitting manuscript. However, some authors indeed don't have department information. How can I fill this form in this condition?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with **"N/A"**. Don't overthink this --- odds are that no one with a say on the acceptance of your paper (editor, reviewers, editor in chief) will ever look at this field. They are only there for the convenience of the journal staff, as far as I understand.

Comment: Which is not to say you won't have a minor inconvenience later dealing with this, as the staff might not initially accept the idea that an author has no affiliation and request it be provided, or try to guess what it "should" be based on an e-mail address or another author, or recycle an old affiliation they had the last time they published with the journal, etc.  I've had all of these happen to me in recent memory, sometimes more than one (or the same one multiple times during the process) on the same submission. So you still have to pay attention, but none of this would disqualify the paper.